# Error rendering data from database with dompdf

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, pdf-generation, dompdf

I'm using DOMPDF library for made a prices list. I installed the library and try with simple pdf and all works ok. In my html template, i'm rendering data from a mysql table. 
This is my HTML :

```
<!-- Html pure code here-->
<?php for ($i=0; $i < count($products); $i++) { ?>
    <section class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3><?=$products[$i]['codigo']?></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h3><?=$products[$i]['titulo']?></h3>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="<?=$products[$i]['img']?>" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 data-producto">
                <div class="descripcion">
                    <?=$products[$i]['descripcion']?>
                </div>
                <div class="precios">
                    <span class="precio">

                    </span>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    <?php } ?>
```

And that's my controller code :

```
    $categorias = $this->post('id_categoria');
$productos = new Modelos\Producto();
// This method make the query and return an array with data.
$products = 
    $productos->get(
        ['id_categoria'=>$categorias],
        null,
        'categoria asc,titulo asc'
    );

//Helpers\Debug::imprimir($listadoProductos);
ob_start();
include 'Layout/electron/listado.tpl.php';
$html1 = ob_get_clean();
if (ob_get_length()) ob_end_clean();

$pdf = new Dompdf();
//exit($html1)
$pdf->loadHtml($html1);
$pdf->render();
$pdf->stream();
```

**The error** : The pdf takes a lot of time to be created. It takes up 3 minutes and sometimes simply it doesn't. 
If a print the pdf without the foreach loop. The pdf is created correctly. If y print only the html, without use dompdf, only in the navigator. the script run in a second. I need to do something more?

**The products table has 45 products only.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug was because I was including bootstrap css file and DOMPDF does not support it correctly. Then I removed bootstrap and edit my file using a custom css and tables instead bootstrap's grid.

That's all.